# Can't start X server on main partition -- Mesa/NVidia conflict?

Tags: partitioning, nvidia, xorg, mesa

I am unable to start my X server any time I try booting my computer -- which is running Ubuntu 14.04 -- from the default partition (i.e., by choosing the first "Ubuntu" option in the GRUB menu). Whenever I boot using the default partition, I get a message that says:

```
The disk drive '/boot/efi' is not ready yet or not present.
Continue to wait, or press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.
```

I have seen this message before and just waiting a few seconds gets rid of it; however, this one remains until I do press S. When I do, I am taken to the login screen. I can choose a user and enter my password, but as soon as I click "OK", all options disappear for a few seconds (leaving the bare wallpaper), then the entire screen turns black briefly and I end up back on the login screen.

Entering a tty terminal and running `startx` as a normal user yields the following output:

```
xinit: Connection to X server lost.
```

Obviously, the connection then fails. When I try `startx` as a root user, the connection is not automatically lost; instead, the list of extension initialization and loading messages hangs after the following four:

```
Loading extension GLX
Loading extension NV-GLX
Loading extension NV-CONTROL
Loading extension XINERAMA
```

And the only way I've found to get out of the hang is to press Ctrl-Backslash.

The really curious aspect of this problem is that my computer has two internal hard drives; thus, the GRUB menu allows me to start my computer on either the "sdb2" (default; the one I've usually used) or "sda2" partitions. And I am perfectly capable of starting the X server on "sda2", but not on "sdb2".

I suspect that the discrepancy may be as a result of the graphics drivers on my machine. The data on these partitions are similar, except that the "sda2" does not contain any of my work from the past two weeks. My computer has NVidia graphics drivers. However, I installed the Mesa 10.1.3 OpenGL libraries on my computer last week (accordingly, they ended up only on "sdb2"). Could the inability to start my X server be as the result of a weird conflict between Mesa and NVidia assets?